# Naming convention nested blocks and elements in BEM in CSS

Tags: html, css, bem

I am a newbie in the BEM world and was looking for some clarity.
The BEM guide advises me to use the following approach:

```
.block {}
.block__elem1 {}
.block__elem2 {}
.block__elem3 {}

<div class='block'>
    <div class='block__elem1'>
        <div class='block__elem2'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='block__elem3'></div>
</div>
```

Let's say I have the following piece of code. It's not clear to me if I should use  `trending-topics__image` and `trending-topics__title`, or `trending-topics--item__image` and `trending-topics--item__title`, or something different for my elements. I feel like `trending-topics__image` and `trending-topics__title` would be too generic, since the `trending-topics` container could also contain a header image or title that needs different styling.

```
<div class="trending-topics">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <a class="trending-topics__item" href="#">
                    <img class="[WHAT NAME SHOULD I USE?]" src="" alt=""/>
                    <span class="[WHAT NAME SHOULD I USE?]">Lorem ipsum</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <a class="trending-topics__item" href="#">
                    <img class="[WHAT NAME SHOULD I USE?]" src="" alt=""/>
                    <span class="[WHAT NAME SHOULD I USE?]">Lorem ipsum</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BEM is very ease to learn and implement. Also there is some point keep in your mind.
1. You should use short name for parent class if you want use modifier later something like this.

```
<div class="t-topic"><div>
```

2. choose simple Element name to you can remember it later. like (unit, thumb, list, item).

This your code.

```
<div class="t-topics">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <a class="t-topics__link" href="#">
                <img class="t-topics__image" src=""/>
                <span class="t-topic__span">Lorem ipsum</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <a class="t-topics__link" href="#">
                <img class="t-topics__image" src=""/>
                <span class="t-topic__span">Lorem ipsum</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There Also other way if you want nested block like this

```
<div class="t-topics">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <a class="link t-topics__link" href="#">
              <img class="link__image" src=""/>
              <img class="link__image link__image--other" src=""/> // Different image                   
              <span class="link__span">Lorem ipsum</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <a class="t-topics__link" href="#">
                <img class="t-topics__image" src=""/>
                <span class="t-topic__span">Lorem ipsum</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can learn more about BEM from this links.

https://www.toptal.com/css/introduction-to-bem-methodology.
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/a-new-front-end-methodology-bem/

Comment: I noticed I messed up the alignment of the <img> and <span> . It looked like they weren't child elements of the <a>, but they are. Is your answer still applicable or does it require some changes?

Comment: What happens when you call it `t-topics__image` and your `t-topics` container gets a new image field in the future? You will have two elements with same class but different styling. How should I deal with this in CSS?

Comment: If you mean <a>, <span>, <img> tags is children of .col-2. you can write the same code.

Comment: No, I don't please check my question. I mean if `t-topics__image` and `t-topic__span` are childs of `t-topics__link`

Comment: let's suppose that you have one image different in t-topics just use modifier like <img class="t-topic__image t-topic__image--one">